# Text before price on WooCom

Tags: functions, code

I want to add text before the price on the WooCommerce product catalogue only, which I have working using this code in functions.php:

```
// Add text before price
function bd_rrp_price_html( $price, $product ) {
    $return_string = 'Rent from: ' . $price;
    return $return_string;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_price_html', 'bd_rrp_price_html', 100, 2 );
```

However, the above function is also adding the text before the price on the product detail page, which I do not want...

What would I need to change in the function to get it so it only displays on the product catalogue?

Thanks.

Comment: Checkout my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this out. Add other conditional tags according to the requirement. Hope it helps.

```
// Add text before price
function bd_rrp_price_html( $price, $product ) {
    if(is_shop()){
        $price = 'Rent from: ' . $price;
    }
    return $price;
    
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_price_html', 'bd_rrp_price_html', 100, 2 );
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: Thanks for your reply. This did not work. Text still shows on the product page, as well as the catalogue.

Comment: It shouldn't. i have tested on my project. Can you share more details?

Comment: Sure... on the product page, you have to select a size, to display the price... that is where the text still shows infront... it might be different because it's a variable product?

Comment: No, it works in the variable products too.

Comment: See, I have uploaded the images. On another note Didi you completely replaced my code with yours?

Comment: Yeah I replaced my code... I may not be referring to the correct area of Price... in your screenshot, you show the Color and Logo as variable options... when you select them, a price appears below them... that is the Price I am referring to. Does that make a difference?

Comment: No, not at all. Still works the same. Updated the picture in answer. Please check.

Comment: Just tested again, and it does not work at all... text Rent them: doesn't even show on the catalogue page. I even removed all other functions to test, to make sure nothing conflicted, and it still didn't work.

Comment: Can you put echo 'here'; exit; on the line above if condition and check if the function is called on the page?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what you mean... where should I place "echo" too?

Comment: above if(is_shop()){ line.

Comment: Ok, that now shows "here" above the price on catalogue, and also on the product page.

Comment: okay, now add the same code after f(is_shop()){ line and remove the previous. See if how it goes.

Comment: Ok, done that, and now it doesn't show anything at all... just the price.

Comment: oh, man. Didn't it print 'here'? If not then the is_shop() condition is failing.